# Set menu item background color on hover in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-theme

I have menu items in my app, and I would like to change color of item background, when it is clicked (please see screenshot - item 1 is clicked)

[image: item 1 is clicked]

I just want one color here - either light blue, or dark one. However, as you can see, there are two of them on the first item.

Here is my code:

Toolbar in activity:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            sothree:theme="@style/MyActionBar"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            style="@style/toolbarButton">

            ...

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Styles:

```
    <style name="toolbarButton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@color/material_dark_blue</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:centerX">@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/material_white</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/CustomOverflowBack</item>
        <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

UPDATE:
Adding `CustomOverflowBack`:

```
    <style name="CustomOverflowBack" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_item</item>
    </style>
```

Menu_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/material_dark_blue" />
    <solid android:color="@color/actionbar_item_bg_color" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Have you try my answer  @Tom11

Comment: post your style "CustomOverflowBack" specified in <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/CustomOverflowBack</item>

Comment: simply remove 
        <item name="android:background">@color/material_dark_blue</item>

Comment: @SachinS style added.

Comment: @Sheychan That would blue color disappear, but the effect would be still the same, in basic colours.

Comment: post your drawable "menu_item" also

Comment: @SachinS menu_item added.

Comment: @Tom11 Did you try my updated answer? It should work for you.

Comment: why do you mix AppCompat and old Holo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this

```
<style name="toolbarButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/material_dark_blue</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerX">@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/material_white</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/CustomOverflowBack</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomOverflowBack" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_item</item>
</style>
```

With this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/AppThemeOverlay.Popup</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeOverlay.Popup" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">popup menu background color</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">selected item color</item>
</style>
```

Here's how you use it:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="?colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:popupTheme="?actionBarPopupTheme"/>
```

The above is enough to make it work on API 21 and above.

I left out your `toolbarButton` style because it's unrelated to the issue.

## Here are some hints

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
```

Do not use platform styles for AppCompat widgets. If you used AppCompat style `@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar` you would have to override virtually *none* of the attributes.

```
<item name="android:background">@color/material_dark_blue</item>
```

Background in a theme will be applied to any view that does not override it. That's why you see the blue square. `android:background` is a *style* attribute, use it on widgets. `android:colorBackground` is a *theme* attribute and it's used (among other things) to color the `android:popupBackground`, which provides the shape of a popup menu.

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/material_white</item>
```

Text color is again more of a style attribute used on TextViews. Widely used theme attributes are `android:textColorPrimary` and `android:textColorSecondary`. Use those instead. `android:textColor` in a theme may produce unexpected/undesired results.

```
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@android:color/white</item>
```

Do *NOT* put a color resource into a style/text appearance attribute. It will not work or crash or worse produce unexpected results without crashing.

Comment: Using this approach, there is default dark grey color, but I need it blue. ColorBackground and colorControlHighlight seems to not work. I used your code, however I have changed app:popupTheme to android:popupTheme, as app: threw me an error (namespace is not bound).

Comment: @Tom11 We don't write `app:` or `android:` for fun, there is a difference and if you change something it will break. If namespace could not be found, select the underlined sentence, press Alt+Enter and choose the `Create namespace declaration` quickfix.

Answer (score 5):

@Tom11 you will have to declare a custom style for you popup overlay of toolbar.

Create a style extending ThemeOverlay:

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item> 
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item> 
</style>
```

> In above style replace @color/colorPrimaryDark  with your background color and @color/colorAccent with your selected background color.

Then use it in you toolbar declaration.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
     android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
     style="@style/toolbarButton"
     app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
```

This will fix your issue.

Update:
Do the following changes:

1. Change `android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"` to `android:background="@color/material_dark_blue"` with your action bar background color in above toolbar item.
2. Remove `<item name="android:background">@color/material_dark_blue</item>` from your MyActionBar style.

Thus the updated code for toolbar and MyActionBar style will be following:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/material_dark_blue"
            style="@style/toolbarButton"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:theme="@style/MyActionBar"/>

 <style name="MyActionBar"
           parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:centerX">@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
```

This should finally work.

Comment: This would work if @Tom11 didn't override `android:background` in a theme resource.

Comment: `MyActionBar` is a *style* not a *theme*. Please learn the difference and use them accordingly. Start here https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/

Comment: @Prati Now it works (I had to change app: to android: in <Toolbar/>), but there is default dark grey color. How to change that? PopupOverlay style seem to not work properly - the colors specified here are not used.

Comment: Thanks. How to set a background color of a checked item? When we expand the menu, all items are shown with the same background.